# Images keep opening in browser instead of running click event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written a small snippet for a `div` section which is shown below.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var links = gallery.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('onclick', function(e) {
      // Hide results
      document.getElementById('placeholder').style.display = 'none';

      // Show loader
      document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';

      // setTimeout(calculateResults, 2000);

      e.preventDefault();
    });

  }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h3>Select Images Below</h3>
  <ul id="imagegallery">
    <li>
      <a href="./img/1.jpg" title="The crowd goes wild">
        <img src="./img/large-1.jpg" alt="the band in concert" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="./img/2.jpg" title="An atmospheric moment">
        <img id='image' src="./img/large-2.jpg" alt="the bassist" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="./img/3.jpg" title="Rocking out">
        <img id='image' src="./img/large-3.jpg" alt="the guitarist" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="./img/4.jpg" title="Encore! Encore!">
        <img id='image' src="./img/large-4.jpg" alt="the audience" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <img id='placeholder' , src="./img/resources/neutral_1.jpg" , alt="Image gooes here" , style="margin-bottom: 50px;padding: 10px;">
  </div>
  <div id="loading">
    <img src="img/loading.gif" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

My main goal is to click the thumbnail image and larger version of this image displays in div below, after showing a loader and added delay, which i want to do dynamically using `JS`. But the problem is whenever i click on image it opens up thumbnail in browser in same window. What am i doing wrong over here.

Comment: try to give `#imagegallery a { display: block; // or inline-block }` in `css`

Comment: It's `click`, not `onclick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root problem you are running into is you are using `addEventListener('onclick')`

this should be: `addEventListener('click')`

"onclick" is the attribute, "click" is the event

Also, you reference `gallery` in the `onload`, unless this is set somewhere higher up, this should just be `document`.

After that's worked out, you'll need to set the source of your placeholder. You can do something like this:

```
links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
   placeholder.src = e.currentTarget.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope this gets you where you need to be.

Comment: thanks the `document` was the problem `gallery` is defined above but its not catching it, anyways thanks for help